# Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded angular SSR Google App Engine

Tags: angular, google-app-engine, angular-universal

I'm getting this error when I try to deploy my Angular NgUniversal App on Google App Engine.

```
ZoneAwarePromise [Promise] {
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]          __zone_symbol__state: 0,
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]          __zone_symbol__value:
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]           Error: Runtime compiler is not loaded
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at Compiler._throwError (/srv/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:25904:15)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at MergeMapSubscriber.project (/srv/node_modules/@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js:3799:57)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at MergeMapSubscriber._tryNext (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:69:27)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at MergeMapSubscriber._next (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/operators/mergeMap.js:59:18)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at MergeMapSubscriber.Subscriber.next (/srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/Subscriber.js:66:18)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at /srv/node_modules/rxjs/internal/util/subscribeToPromise.js:7:24
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/srv/dist/server.js:537:26)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at Object.onInvoke (/srv/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js:26371:37)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at ZoneDelegate.invoke (/srv/dist/server.js:536:52)
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]               at Zone.run (/srv/dist/server.js:296:43) },
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]       scheduleFn: undefined,
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]       cancelFn: undefined,
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]       callback: [Function],
2020-04-26 17:03:52 default[20200421t200653]       invoke: [Function] } }
```

Everything works fine when I click through the pages. But the above error is logging on App Engine.

I have Google for days now and I just can't find out why this is happening.

If anyone would be able to help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: It seems that this has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59126915/uncaught-in-promise-error-runtime-compiler-is-not-loaded-angular-8)

Comment: Show us your routing files